# Using aspnetBoilerplate Templates in VS express

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I want to use AspNetboilerplate (MVC) template to design application in VS-2015 express edition ,but unable to build the project as it gives some reference errors.

Can we use this boilerplate template in express edition or do we need any license version for this??.

Can anyone please guide me on this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install **Visual Studio 15.3.X or up** to be able to compile.

Comment: how to check angular version?